# Equivalent of "Shared with other computers" via terminal in Fedora Server

Tags: wireless-networking, fedora, network-shares, forwarding

I have several computers connected into a network with Fedora Server installed:

[image]

Where one computer has 2 interfaces: WiFi and Ethernet.

- WiFi is used for outer network access (and Internet too).
- Ethernet is
  used for connection to network switch and to other computers
  connected to this switch.

I need to allow internet access for all computers connected to switch.
To achieve, what I need I do following:

- during installation from USB-live I select the WiFi network
- after that I select the Ethernet interface, go to `IPv4 Settings` and select `Shared to other computers`

As result:

- This computer automatically shares Internet access to other computers connected to switch
- Each freshly connected computer to switch automatically obtains it own IP address in the same subnet as computer with WiFi

How to achieve the same using terminal?

I found and tried several options:

1. ```
   parprouted eth0 wlan0
   sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
   ```
  2.

```
sudo
ip addr add 192.168.0.1/24 dev eth0
iptables -A FORWARD -o wlan0 -i eth0 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Neither worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed to do is:

Edit `/etc/sysconfig/network-script/ifcfg-"name_of_interface"`. Find there a lines with parameters:

- `BOOTPROTO` and set it to `BOOTPROTO=shared`
- `IPV6_AUTOCONF` and set it as `IPV6_AUTOCONF=shared`
- `IPV6_PRIVACY` and set it as`IPV6_PRIVACY=no`